# Hangfire Authentication from DataContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, hangfire

I am trying to setup Hangfire so that only Admin users can access the dashboard. My `User` model has a property `UserRole` that I can compare against the parent enum.

However, I'm confused as to how I go about passing the DataContext into the Authorization filter from within Startup.cs.

Is there a different way I should be trying access the User object?

(I'm using entity framework)

#### Startup.cs

```
public void Configure(IApplication app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    ...
    loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();

        app.UseHangfireDashboard("/hangfire", new DashboardOptions()
        {
            //ERROR here because I'm not passing in DataContext,
            //but I'm not sure how to do that...
            Authorization = new [] { new HangfireAuthorizationFilter() }
        });

        app.UseHangfireServer();
    ...
}

public class HangfireAuthorizationFilter : Controller, IDashboardAuthorizationFilter
{
    private readonly DataContext _context;

    public HangfireAuthorizationFilter(DataContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public bool Authorize([NotNull] DashboardContext context)
    {
        var currentUserId = int.Parse(User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value);

        try {
            var userFromRepo = _context.Users.First(u => u.Id == currentUserId);
            return userFromRepo.UserRole == UserRole.Admin;
        catch {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Should I be saving the user to cookies and retrieving it somehow?

Comment: Why are you using hangfire .Net-core has built in support for background services via HostedServices

Comment: My manager likes to use the hangfire dashboard. But I will definitely look into the HostedServices

Comment: Okay cool, I just wanted to let you know there were other options ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I had mine setup:

```
public class HangfireAuthorizationFilter : IDashboardAuthorizationFilter
{
    public bool Authorize(DashboardContext context)
    {
        if (context.GetHttpContext().User.Identity.IsAuthenticated 
              && context.GetHttpContext().User.IsInRole("admin"))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Of course, you could replace the string "admin" with your UserRole.Admin.ToString()